# how do i remove classes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i remove classes with jQuery?

I have this "template" i am working on and i want a "settings" box to the left where the user can change the "color scheme" of the navigation.

I have like 5-10 colors and i cant get it to work.

```
$(".color-orange").click(function () {
  $("#nav").addClass("color-orange");
});
```

How can i then remove the class "color-orange" and add a new class if someone clicks on green?

Well i used this..

```
$(".color-green").click(function () {
      $("#nav").removeClass("color-orange");
      $("#nav").addClass("green");
    });
```

But that just takes orange away. And will not work if you clicked another color.. 
Sorry for my english, and yes. Its my first time here :)

Kind Regards / Albin

Comment: it should work as expected, as for me

Comment: concatenate it $("#nav").removeClass("color-orange").addClass("green"); to make it short.

Comment: anyway, for consistency, why orange is "color-orange" and green just "green"?

Comment: you should not use $(".color-green").click() to bind event. It may bind event on the #nav as well because #nav will have that class. Try using ids for colors i.e. #color-green and so on for your color picker

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$("#nav").removeClass().addClass("green");
```

Without arguments [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) will remove all the classes.

Also don't reselect `$("#nav")` again and again, use method chaining, this increases performance.

Comment: Thank you dfsq, you rock! Worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

The below code will simply overwrite existing classes to whatever you set (in this case "green").

```
$("#nav").attr("class", "green");
```

Since this has gained enough upvotes, I'll tell you why this is kind of better answer than the above one. The one with `removeClass()`.

First, you get the required element, that is `$("#nav")`.

Then, you call a property of JQuery, `removeClass()`.

Then, you again call another property of JQuery, `addClass()`.

In the solution I suggested:

First, you get the element, then call the propery `attr()`, and that's it.

So, it's one step lesser.

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
$('[class^="color-"]').each(function() {
  $("#nav").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("class"));
}
```

or as xFortyFourx pointed out:

```
$('[class^="color-"]').each(function() {
  $("#nav").attr("class",$(this).attr("class"));
}
```

---

Alternative - if I assume you have

```
.green { color:green; .... } /* for the nav */
.color-green { color:green; .... } /* for the settings */
```

you can do

```
$('[class^="color-"]').each(function() {
  $("#nav").attr("class",$(this).attr("class").replace("color-",""));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `removeClass` and do not pass any class to `removeClass` and it will remove all classes that element has.

```
$(".color-green").click(function () {
  $("#nav").removeClass().addClass("green");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".color-green").click(function () {
      $("#nav").removeClass("color-orange");
      $("#nav").removeClass("next-color");
      $("#nav").removeClass("another-color");
      $("#nav").removeClass("yet-another-color-but-green");
      $("#nav").addClass("green");
});
```

Comment: it is not an efficient way

Comment: dan you saw dfsq solution. I knew about `removeClass` but dfsq was first to answer and we are just to help here not to repeat answers of each other as Adil did.

Comment: excuse me officer, my answer was like 5 seconds later. I apoligize deeply for the lives I ruined.

Comment: nah i was just talking about Adil not you :D don't be HYPER buddy. well, i like the style you commented. Thumbs up.